# Embedding web browser window in Java - bump

Tags: java, swing, javafx, browser

Context: I'm trying to use Microsoft's API to login into an account for my game. While I did find a documentation on how to use it I got stuck when the actual login part comes in. So, I decided it would be easier to use a browser window to login and I started searching.

Only posts I could find are 10+ year old posts with discontiued libraries, or 1000$ libraries. The point of this post: What modern **free** Java Swing/JavaFX library can I use?
(preferably one that I can get the website source from), also I have tried JxBrowser [image] and it seems that it needs payment, and MozSwing seems dead.

Comment: Maybe try https://vaadin.com/

Comment: Does not seem to be what I'm looking for, I just want to launch a browser window on a set website with Swing, or JavaFX

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots to text, inline it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).